# Why does the bot react itself? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm setting up a bot, who will await for a user's reaction to write a short message. Currently, the bot responds itself to his reaction! Why?

```
const { Client, RichEmbed, Discord } = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');
const client= new Client();


client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('je suis pret!');
    client.user.setActivity("/help pour appeler de l'aide (avec le code NOMAD bien sur)", { type: 'WATCHING' });

})
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    console.log(`${user.username} reacted with "${reaction.emoji.name}".`);
});

client.on('messageReactionRemove', (reaction, user) => {
    console.log(`${user.username} removed their "${reaction.emoji.name}" reaction.`);
});
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return; 

    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('!rea')) {
      try {
        const sentMessage = await message.channel.send('Select a number.');

        for (let n = 1; n <= 5; n++) await sentMessage.react(`${n}⃣`);

        const filter = (reaction, user) => ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'].includes(reaction.emoji.name.slice(0, 1)) && user.id === message.author.id;
        const collected = await sentMessage.awaitReactions(filter, { maxMatches: 1, time: 60000 });

        if (collected.size === 0) {
          await sentMessage.clearReactions();
          await message.channel.send('Your time ran out.');
        } else {
          const reaction = collected.first();

          switch(reaction.emoji.name.slice(0, 1)) {
            case '1':
              await message.channel.send('You chose `one`.');
              break;
          }
        }
      } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  });
client.login(config.token);
```

I found the problem: the bot considers the first message: "!rea", so if I add the reaction below !rea, it answers!
How can I fix this, because I want that he considered the embed reactions!

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client's [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message) event is emitted by *any* message, including those sent by itself.

To prevent bots (and therefore your client as well) from triggering the code, add a condition checking the author's [`User.bot`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=bot) property at the beginning of the callback, and return if it's `true`.

```js
if (message.author.bot) return; // Stop if the author is a bot.

// Continue with your code.
```

Additionally, you're collecting reactions on the wrong message, and on every one. `message` *outside* of your first `then()` callback is the one the bot *received*.

To make things much more simple and readable, we can use the `await` keyword (note that it can only be used asynchronous context, like in a function declared as async).

Combining these changes...

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return; 

  if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('!rea')) {
    try {
      const sentMessage = await message.channel.send('Select a number.');

      for (let n = 1; n <= 5; n++) await sentMessage.react(`${n}⃣`);

      const filter = (reaction, user) => ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'].includes(reaction.emoji.name.slice(0, 1)) && user.id === message.author.id;
      const collected = await sentMessage.awaitReactions(filter, { maxMatches: 1, time: 60000 });

      if (collected.size === 0) {
        await sentMessage.clearReactions();
        await message.channel.send('Your time ran out.');
      } else {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        switch(reaction.emoji.name.slice(0, 1)) {
          case '1':
            await message.channel.send('You chose `one`.');
            break;
        }
      }
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, unfortunately, adding this line of code, it does nothing and after 60 seconds, in the console.log, it's showing "ReferenceError: channel is not defined"

Comment: Don't add another `message` event listener, just insert the `if` statement at the very top. No bot's message will trigger the code anymore, so it should be stopping your loop. In your `catch()` callback for awaiting messages, `channel` isn't defined. Use `message.channel`.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand: I have to remove "if (message.content ...)"? But how can the bot know when to launch?

PS: at the .catch, I added "message." at the channel.send ('...')

Comment: Add this `if` statement as the very first line within the callback (underneath `client.on(...`).

Comment: I did it, but the bot still does not respond to the reaction

Comment: only "not in time..." after 60 seconds

Comment: Please check my revised answer.

Comment: This time, after the appearance of the 5 reactions, I press a reaction, but nothing is happening. And after 60 seconds, nothing happens, no error message.

Comment: You're going to need to change the code to do something with the user's choice. As an example I added a section for the number 1 but it doesn't do anything at all. If you'd like an error message instead of the reactions cleared, you can change that as well.

Comment: I don't understand. Do I need to change all of this code?

Comment: I added a line, can you see it?

Comment: Check this code again. Right now, only reacting with the number 1 will do anything; I'm not sure what exactly you want to do with each separate reaction. Follow the pattern and add more `case` statements to tailor the code to your needs.

Comment: I prefer to take them separately to be able to code an individual sequel to each reaction (but as I am a beginner, it may be a mistake)

Comment: You can add code for each individual reaction as it's written. Not sure I understand?

Comment: With what's shown right now, it should. I've only coded for the number 1 reaction solely as an example.

Comment: it is possible that the problem comes from the top of code (like const client= new Client();)?

Comment: Ok, after 1 minute, it works. Thank you for your help @slothiful